# How is 'classOf' expression represented in scala AST

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I'm new to the Scala AST concepts.

I need to traverse a Scala code tree that contains an expression such as:
`classOf[org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils]`

I need to be able to identify this case when pattern matching on `scala.reflect.internal.Trees.Tree`.

For instance I know that it is not `case _:Apply`

What is the correct pattern in order to successfuly match this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `classOf[C]` is represented as a `Literal(value)`, where `value.tag == ClazzTag`, and `value.typeValue` is a `Type` representing `C`. You can match on it as:

```scala
case Literal(value) if value.tag == ClazzTag =>
  val tpe = value.typeValue
  // do something with `tpe`
```

See https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/ec5b328330276b9feb20cccadd75e19d27e887d3/compiler/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/nscplugin/GenJSCode.scala#L2043 for a real-world example.